# android wallpaper changed

Tags: android, desktop-wallpaper

Hi I set a android wallpaper through bitmap.
But Now I want to remove this .How can I remove this??
Can anyone have better Idea.I try wallpaper.clear(); but it is not working .

SO please Help me .

Thanks and Regards,
Md Maidul Islam

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by removing it? If you want to set it back to the old wallpaper, save the old wallpaper before setting the new one, then switch it back when you want to 'remove'.

Answer (score 0):

wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
                wallpaperManager.clear();

this will return the android default image

Comment: Please remember that [`clear()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#clear%28%29) must be inside a `try { } catch (IOException e) {}` block.